# control id change automatically in MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

why id of control changed automatically when we use it in masterpage , while in simple page it does not change??

this is source code after run the MasterPage

as  :: `<input name="ctl00$cp1$txtUName" type="text" id="ctl00_cp1_txtUName" style="width:128px;" />`

this is source code after run Simple Page

AS:`<input name="txtUName" type="text" id="txtUName" />`

these are same controls

Comment: i strongly doubt that. are you sure the input doesn't have runat="server" on it? as is this the only way controls get an ID like that.

Comment: @RPM1984: Of course I have runat="server". What I wrote in my question is the html after the page got rendered. The original control was <asp:TextBox ID="txtUName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: ok - in that case the answer in simple, on the master page it's picking up a prefix from the container. standard asp.net practice. if you put the "simple page" one inside say a asp:placeholder with runat=server, it's ID will also get changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this problem has arisen from some javascript you're using which no longer references the correct ID (because its changed).  If so when you send your javascript from the server use the clientID method.  So for example `alert('<%= txtUName.ClientID %>')` will generate an alertbox with the correct ID contained at runtime

Answer (score 4):

That is not true, when you use input control with runat="server" it's id will be generated by server. If you are using asp.net 4.0 then you can use `CliendIDMode="static"` in `<% @page ...` declaration to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have used a TextboxControl in your master page and that what your showing in your question is the resulting HTML.

The master page is a [naming container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx) (it's really a user control that gets injected in the page's control hierarchy). All the children of a naming container gets the containers name as prefix in order to disambiguate the control name from controls with the same name inside another container.